# Highlight mll and mly files

Tags: emacs, ocaml, tuareg, typerex

I am rewriting my `.emacs`. At the moment, `.ml` files are well highlighted, whereas there is no mode for `.mll` or `.mly` files. Here is my [.emacs](http://pastebin.com/xMNn347N), does anyone know how to amend it?

Additionally, am I using `tuareg-mode` or `ocp-indent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you want to use tuareg for `.mll` and `.mly`, you can add those lines:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.mll\\'" . tuareg-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.mly\\'" . tuareg-mode))
```

You are using both tuareg and ocp-indent. But I think this is ocp-indent that is handling the indentation.

Comment: These 2 lines do highlight `.mll` and `.mly`. But when I type `TAB`, the indentation is very odd, how could I make indentation work?

Comment: You can't for now since theses modes were not done for `.mll` and `.mly` files. It pisses me off too but that's how it is for now...